# Vector subscript out of range in function

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, knapsack-problem

I'm using a 2D vector for this knapsack function, and it keeps returning vector out of range (line 1733), but the vectors shouldn't be going over their size and causing an overflow. Changing the for loops to < as opposed to <= has no effect.

```
int knapsack(int cap, vector<int>& weight, vector<int>& value, int n)
{
    vector<vector<int>> K;
    K.resize(cap, vector<int>(n));
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= cap; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                K[i][j] = 0;
            else if (weight[i - 1] <= j)
            {
                K[i][j] = max(weight[i - 1] + K[i - 1][j - weight[i - 1]], K[i - 1][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                K[i][j] = K[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return K[i][j];
}
```

From what I've read about it, resizing would be the solution, but I've already done that with the proper variables for the size of the vector. Or would I need to use pushback instead?

Comment: "vectors shouldn't be going over their size and causing an overflow" - Of course you think your program is correct, but you make mistakes just like everyone else. Your vector is `cap` by `n`, but you index it as if its `n` by `cap`. The `<=` is also a bug.

Comment: Just because changing something doesn't fix the problem doesn't mean it's not a bug. It just means it's not the only bug. When you debug, don't make assumptions about where the bug is, because the fact that you have a bug in the first place shows that you can be wrong.

Comment: `<=` in a for loop always sets off my Spider-sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Vector indexing

When you declare `K` as follows:

```
vector<vector<int>> K;
K.resize(cap, vector<int>(n));
```

Then the vector `K` has length `cap`, and each vector `K[i]` has length `n`. However, in your for-loop I see:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= cap; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            K[i][j] = 0;
        ...
    }
}
```

It looks like the order of the indices is wrong here, because in the `if`-statement you can either set `K[n][0]` or `K[0][cap - 1]`, when the only valid maximum indices are `K[cap - 1][0]` and `K[0][n - 1]` here.

Using `push_back()` is safer. In that case, don't forget to reserve space to avoid unnecessary reallocations.

## Loop range

As mentioned by others in the comments, when iterating over `n` elements, the proper way to write this is:

```
for (i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
```

So no '<= n', as then it would access the 'cap + 1'th element.

## After the loop, iterators will point beyond the end of the loop

Once a loop like `for (i = 0; i < cap; ++i)` is done, it will have increased `i` to the value `cap`. So the last line:

```
return K[i][j];
```

Will for sure be accessing the vector out of range. You should write something like:

```
return K[cap - 1][n - 1];
```

Alternatively, you can use the member function [`back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) to access the last element of a vector, and write:

```
return K.back().back();
```

## Unused function parameter

Why is there a parameter `value` when that is not used at all in this function?

## Assert that `weight` has the right size

Another possible source of accessing a vector out of range could be that the vector `weight` doesn't have the right size. You can add an `assert()` to your code to catch this mistake in debug builds:

```
#include <cassert>
...
int knapsack(int cap, vector<int>& weight, vector<int>& value, int n)
{
    assert(weight.size() >= n - 1);
    ...
```

Comment: So I reversed them to be K.resize(n, vector<int>(cap)) and I still get the overflow. When I tried reversing the order of the indices in the for loop I had the same problem.

Comment: Your sizes need to be `n+1` and `cap+1` as your for loops use `<=` for their limits